# Round Number with different length

Tags: python

I am grabbing data from the [WSJ](http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-tradingdiary2-20120830.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar), specifically the `Adv. volume*` and `Decl. volume*` numbers.

So with this example I need to round the first 6 digits. For instance Adv. volume* has the number 92,461,567 and would be rounded to 92,462. In some cases the number for this could be something like 921,324,745 in which case it would round to 921,325. I only need the first 2 sets of numbers whether there is 2 or 3 numbers in the first set split by the commas. I do use the round function but it does not always round correctly for me.

An example of how I am doing this is as follows:

```
Adv_Vol = Adv_Vol.replace(',','')
Adv_Vol = '%d' % (round(float(Adv_Vol[:7])))
```

What would be the way to do this so that it is accurate and handles whether there are 2 or 3 digits in the first set of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have decimals, so you shouldn't be rounding in the first place. Do this:

```
>>> x = "123,456,789"
>>> y = "23,456,789"
>>> xi = int(x.replace(',', ''))
>>> yi = int(y.replace(',', ''))
>>> print xi / 1000
123456
>>> print yi / 1000
23456
>>> print int(round(xi, -3))/1000
123457
>>> print int(round(yi, -3))/1000
23457
```

Comment: in your example though it should be 123457 for xi and not 123456, I need to round up the 6 to a 7 since the next number is 7. Agreed about the decimals for rounding but I need to round in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cut the last 3 digits that would be quite easy:

```
Adv_Vol = '92,461,567'
stripped = Adv_Vol.replace(',','')[:-3] # returns 92461
```

but if you need a rounding, then it's still not very complicated:

```
rounded = int(round(float(Adv_Vol.replace(',',''))/1000.0)) # returns 92462
```